# Update content Dropdown list via Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, webforms

I'm struggling with the following and I'm not even sure if it's possible at all.

I have, at start, two pull down menus. Menu one with suppliers and (currently) a second pull down with all size of photos that are in the database. Where I want to go to is that when selecting a supplier, the second pull down menu changes with the option this supplier provides. So far nothing difficult using Jquery and use the output to update the second pull down menu.

Now comes the difficult part. I use the second drop down to insert their information. So the second pull down menu, could be be dozen of them, are all the same. I use a JS script to copy the table row of the form. Since an ID should be unique, these pull downs don't have an ID.

Is it still possible to update all of these 'second' pull down menu's on change of the first pull down menu? And if so, how is it possible?

The first pulldown that should trigger the update of the dropdowns below:

```
<select name="leverancier" id="leveranciers">
    <option value="1">Supplier 1</option>
    <option value="2">Supplier 2</option>
</select>
```

This part gets duplicated:

```
<tr>
<td>
<select name="type[]" class="test">
    <option value="1">9x13</option>
    <option value="2">10x15</option>
    <option value="3">11x14</option>
</select>           
</td>
<td><input type="text" name="min_euro[]"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="max_euro[]"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<select name="type[]" class="test">
    <option value="1">9x13</option>
    <option value="2">10x15</option>
    <option value="3">11x14</option>
</select>           
</td>
<td><input type="text" name="min_euro[]"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="max_euro[]"></td>
</tr>
```

Thanks

Ralf

Comment: Do you have some sample code you'd be willing to share?

Comment: @Ralf: Do you code or just talk about code? It's really boring to read a question like that.

Comment: @Bhesh, I do code. I will add a sample....

Comment: I don't think I understand the question. What do you mean "use the second drop down to insert their information?" Updating the content of one SELECT based on the value of another SELECT is pretty straightforward.

Comment: @Tom, the update of the content of one select to the other is simple. In this case I can have more then one 'second' select field. Therefore I can't use the ID's for each of these. So the straightforward option doesn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give each secondary SELECT the same class.

Then, define an event handler on the primary SELECT that updates secondary SELECTs by targeting that class.

E.g.:

```
jQuery('#leveranciers').bind('change', function(event) {
  // somehow determine the new set of options for all secondary SELECTs
  jQuery('SELECT.secondary').each(function(i, e) {
    jQuery(e).html(newOptionsMarkup);
  });
  return true;
});
```

(Please ignore the terrible `.html()`-based approach. The important piece is the way updates are targeted.)

Comment: This works perfectly. Sometime the solution is not that difficult. Thanks Tom.